# Trying to access EntityHome in EntityController returns nullpointer

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, seam, transactional

I'd like to take the queries out of the EntityController and put it in the EntityHome component but it keeps returning nullpointer. I cannot figure out the error, the TransactionAttribute has something with it?

The controller:

```
@Name("hElementController")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@AutoCreate
@BypassInterceptors
public class HElementController extends EntityController
{
 ...
    @In(create=true)
    private HElementHome hElementHome;

    ...
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<TreeNode> doSth(HClassifier classifier)
    {
    ...
        //hElementHome is null
        //nullpointer happens here
        List<Object[]> result = hElementHome.getElementsDTO(classifier.getId(), elementStatus);
    ...
    }
}
```

HElementController  cannot resolve hElementHome.getElementsDTO because hElementHome is null.
And the EntityHome:

```
@Name("hElementHome")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@AutoCreate
public class HElementHome extends SignalHome<HElement>
{
    @Transactional
    @TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<Object[]> getElementsDTO(Integer classifierId, Integer statusId)
    {
    ...some query
    return query.getResultList();
    }
 ...
}
```

My testng method:

```
new ComponentTest()
{
    protected void testComponents() throws Exception
    {
        HElementController hElementController = (HElementController)
        getValue("#{hElementController}");
        HElementHome hElementHome = (HElementHome)
        getValue("#{hElementHome}");
        ...

        List<TreeNode> actualList = hElementController.getElementsDTO(
            person1, 
            classifier1);
        ...
```

I have tried n ways to inject the home into the controller but wasn't successful.
Guess I'm missing something between the transactions.

Adding stacktrace

```
[http-127.0.0.1-9050-4] WARN org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog - Narrowing proxy to class com.m.youknow.model.Person - this operation breaks ==
[http-127.0.0.1-9050-2] WARN org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog - Narrowing proxy to class com.m.youknow.model.Person - this operation breaks ==
[http-127.0.0.1-9050-2] ERROR com.m.youknow.util.SignalViewHandler - Error Rendering View[/viewPerson.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /include/inc_elementBreadCrumbDTO.xhtml @19,122 value="#{hElementController.getElementsDTO(classifier.id, elementStatus)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:617)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getValue(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1647)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:621)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:339)
org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:324)
org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.html.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:63)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)



Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /include/inc_elementBreadCrumbDTO.xhtml @19,122 value="#{hElementController.getElementsDTO(classifier.id, elementStatus)}":
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:76)
javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:614)
... 90 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.m.youknow.element.HElementController.getElementsDTO(HElementController.java:95)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
 ... 91 more



[lifecycle] JSF1054: (Phase ID: RENDER_RESPONSE 6, View ID: /viewPerson.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@9df9a2]
[[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.youknow.element.HElementController.doSth(HElementController.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:67)
at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:614)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getValue(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1647)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:621)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:339)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:324)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.html.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:63)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:239)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.renderRow(TableRenderer.java:309)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeChildren(TableRenderer.java:133)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:186)
at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:166)
at org.jboss.seam.ui.renderkit.CacheRendererBase.doEncodeChildren(CacheRendererBase.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.ui.util.cdk.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:92)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:406)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.milestone.youknow.interceptor.TimeFilter.doFilter(TimeFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It's strange because the stackstrace do not shows the exactly the moment where the controller calls hElementHome.getElementsDTO(..). In debug mode I can see that hElementHome is null.

I'm usign: Seam version: 2.2.2 Jboss 5.0.1

Comment: post the full stacktrace maybe it will be useful to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HElementController class is annotated

```
@BypassInterceptors
```

so Seam interceptors (including bijection interceptors) will not be called upon the doSth() method execution, which means hElementHome will always be null. You need to remove @BypassInterceptors or get a reference to the hElementHome component using Component.getInstance() in your doSth() method. Depending on your app architecture, you may need to ask Component.getInstance() to always instantiate the component (see javadocs) or annotate HElementHome with @AutoCreate.